# How can i add context menu for each item on listView1 and treeView1 when doing mouse right click on item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The items in the listView1 are files so i want that the menu for each file when i will do on the file right click with the mouse will show different options(properties) then if i'm doing right clikc with the mouse on treeView1 item since the items on the treeView1 are directories.

How can i make that on right click on specific item when the mouse cursor is over an item it will show a menu with options for this item ?

The listView! MouseUp event:

```
private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if (listView1.FocusedItem.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) == true)
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
            }
        }
    }
```

The treeView1 MouseUp event:

```
    private void treeView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            // Select the clicked node
            treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

            if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
            {
                myContextMenuStrip.Show(treeView1, e.Location);
            }
        }
    }
```

And a method i did but not sure if need to use it:

```
    private MenuItem AddMenuItem(ContextMenu cm, string text, EventHandler handler, object context)
    {
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem(text, handler);
        item.Tag = context;
        cm.MenuItems.Add(item);
        return item;
    }
```

Comment: Handle the [ContextMenuStrip.Opening()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening(v=vs.110).aspx) event, which shows **before** the menu is opened.  From there you can determine the currently selected file/folder and change the menus accordingly before the menu is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differentiate between the file and directory node by giving them specific name  using TreeNode.Name property. In the COntextMenuStrip.Opening event, you can then enable or disable the menu items based on the node name.

```
TreeNode tn = treeView1.GetNodeAt( e.X, e.Y );

if( tn != null )
{
  if( tn.Name == "FileName") {

  }
}
```